# PhoneGap Build is using wrong index.html file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-cli

When I upload my PhoneGap project to PhoneGap Build, install and launch the app, the wrong index.html file is being used. The config file has:

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

In my project, the www files look like:

```
fr/index.html
images/*
res/*
scripts/*
styles/*
index.html
```

What happens is that it chooses the fr/index.html file and seems to use the fr folder as the root as none of the custom icons and splash screens work. It adds the PhoneGap ones.

If I remove the wrong index.html file, it works. The reason I have two like that is all files in the root folder can be accessed in the different language folder. So index.html is the main English and fr/index.html is the French version of the same page and so on.

Is there a way to make sure it targets the root index.html (www/index.html)?

Comment: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
 -- [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) -- 
[Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)

Comment: Use one index.html, a skeleton, and then load in the language localised text with scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to specify the index.html file to PhoneGapBuild because it can't be anything else than index.html at www folder,
and for the splash screens they must be at the res folder, there is a well defined packaging mode to work with PhoneGapBuild that you have to respect in order to use it.

example for splash for android :

```
 <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
```

you can look at the official hello world example here for more details :
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml